# SQL Server indexing with Power BI

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Do I have to create index in SQL Server table when I import data into Power BI Desktop? Or will Power BI handle it?

Also what about direct query? should I create index on SQL Server or not?

Thanks,
Ed Dror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes when using direct query you should create an indexing on SQL Server to increase performance